# Cannot get url plugin settings page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to get the plugin settings URL for my plugin as follows:

```
$settings_page_url = menu_page_url( 'zrdn-settings', false );
```

I've added the menu page as follows:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'zrdn_menu_pages' );

// Adds module to left sidebar in wp-admin for ZLRecipe
function zrdn_menu_pages() {
    // Add the top-level admin menu
    $page_title = 'Zip Recipes Plugin Settings';
    $menu_title = 'Zip Recipes Plugin';
    $capability = 'manage_options';
    $menu_slug = 'zrdn-settings';
    $function = 'zrdn_settings';
    add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, 'dashicons-carrot');

    // Add submenu page with same slug as parent to ensure no duplicates
    $settings_title = 'Settings';
    add_submenu_page($menu_slug, $page_title, $settings_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
}
```

`$settings_page_url` ends up being an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get url using

`$url = admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=' . $_GET['page']`

Comment: ...sure, that might work, but fact of the matters is that menu_page_url() isn't working as advertised or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.(Of course in Theme)

Solution: The `menu_page_url` function only works if it comes with `admin_init` or `admin_menu`.
When you add the menu, you can get the url there and save it somewhere.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'zrdn_menu_pages' );

// Adds module to left sidebar in wp-admin for ZLRecipe
function zrdn_menu_pages() {
    // Add the top-level admin menu
    $page_title = 'Zip Recipes Plugin Settings';
    $menu_title = 'Zip Recipes Plugin';
    $capability = 'manage_options';
    $menu_slug = 'zrdn-settings';
    $function = 'zrdn_settings';
    add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, 'dashicons-carrot');

    // Add submenu page with same slug as parent to ensure no duplicates
    $settings_title = 'Settings';
    add_submenu_page($menu_slug, $page_title, $settings_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
    // SET URL
    $get_start_url = menu_page_url($menu_slug, false);
    //wp_die(var_export($get_start_url));         // for debug
    //save
    // update_option(key, value);
    update_option("kdks_get_start_url", esc_url_raw($get_start_url));
}
// GET URL
if(get_option("kdks_get_start_url", null) != null){
    $url = get_option("kdks_get_start_url");
    //do somewere..
}
```

I hope your problem is solved